# which component is best for display text's

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I want to know which component is best to display multiple line of text's( just like help option in project's)..i want to add help option(details text to be display) to display while clicking in certain component
Thank's in advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

multiple lines is best handled natively by text and textArea. Use text for display only and textArea if the user will need to edit the entry.